# Stop Table View From Repeating Background Image in Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

I'm designing my first iOS app (first time here on Stackoverflow) and am using the follow code in my MasterViewController.m under viewDidLoad to display a custom background for my Table View.

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookshelfbg.jpg"]];
```

The is meant to display a background for the entire table and the cells have their own background. The problem is that each cell uses it's background (which is mostly transparent) but also tiles or starts over the background image I set for the table view. I have changed the background of the individual cells to clear and that just completely removes the cell background image that I have set.

Here is the code for my cells under (UITableViewCell):

```
    {UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];
    BookQueueDoc *book = [self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shelfcellbg.png"]];
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`cell.contentView` isn't all cell area. Try just `cell.backgroundColor`